# BarButtonItem not connecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation controller,root view, and then is the main menu. Pressing a button opens a tab bar controller with 2 tabs both having custom table views. I added the title on navigation bar and then i added a button on the right side. So far so good. The button will be used to show an action sheet. Basically there are a lot of other ways to show an action sheet but it has to be done with that button. Thing is that the button is showing correctly but i can't trigger an action. It will not connect with my ViewController assigned to the 2 tabs. I have tried to create the barbuttonitem programmatically in viewDidLoad with no luck. How can i program this button to open an action sheet?This is the Hierarchy of the tab bar controller.tab bar -> navigation item -> bar button item.

edited

```
UIBarButtonItem *actionSheetButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                           initWithTitle:@"Options"                                            
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                           target:self 
                           action:@selector(showActionSheet)];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actionSheetButton;
```

Comment: Please post your code for generating your nav bar button.

Comment: You didnt have to do this programmatically at all, simply create an IBAction from this button and call the showActionSheet

Comment: Adding on to what @meda said, control-drag the barbutton item into your implementation and it will create a method that's called for you.

Comment: I know. Thing is i cannot create an IBAction an outlet or whatever. I control drag and nothing happens. Probably that's the reason why if i do it programmatically it doesn't even appear

Comment: @Whiteshadow then you are doing something wrong, make sure the right class open or it wont let you drag n drop

Comment: That's what i though. The tab bar controller's class is UITabBarController. The 2 tabs i have are the same ViewController i created. If i add a button on one tab, programmatically or not, it won't appear when running. So i cannot press anything. If i add the button on the tab controller, it is of a different class, it will appear correctly but i can't connect it.

Comment: If i change the superclass of my view controller from UIViewController to UITabBarController it will let me add the button as an IBAction BUT it will break my navigation controller. So if i change that how can i fix my navigation controller ?